# How to format the output of an array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please, this might be a very easy question for the python guys out there but for a beginner like me, I am finding it a bit though.
I have an array with random, unsorted numbers..and I am looping through it and each time, I want it to print something like this :

```
i:number in the array..
0:3
1:5
2:6
3:2
```

So, first it prints the index of i followed by a : character and next it prints the number in that ith index

Here is my code but I don't know how to display this..

```
for i in range(len(numberInput)):
     print numberInput[i]
```

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: By the way, you should have a look at the PEP8 conventions: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ It won't change the way your code works, but it will be more Pythonesque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> lis = [3,5,6,2]
>>> for ind, item in enumerate(lis):
...     print "{}:{}".format(ind, item)
...     
0:3
1:5
2:6
3:2
```